# Solve the equation $x^7- 2ix^4 - ix^3 -2 = 0$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

I am having difficulty factorising the equation.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. You can collect $(x^4-i)$:
$$x^7- 2ix^4 - ix^3 -2=x^3(x^4-i)- 2i(x^4-i)=(x^4-i)(x^3-2i).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: In this case look at the first and the third term and then compare with the others.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will do it.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^7-ix^3-2ix^4-2=0\\(x^7-ix^3)-2(ix^4+1)=0\\
x^3(x^4-i)-2(ix^4+1)=0\\\frac{i}{i}x^3(x^4-i)-2(ix^4+1)=0\\
\frac{1}{i}x^3(ix^4-i^2)-2(ix^4+1)=0\\
\frac{1}{i}x^3(ix^4+1)-2(ix^4+1)=0\\ 
(\frac{x^3}{i}-2)(ix^4+1)=0\\
(\frac{x^3-2i}{i})(ix^4+1)=0\\ \to
(x^3-2i)(ix^4+1)=0\\$$

Comment: note that $i^2=-1$